# Using Ant taskdef and loaderref in Gradle build

Tags: gradle, ant

I have an Ant build, and I'd like to convert to Gradle. The Ant build makes use of a few custom tasks. Ant build.xml looks like

```
<project name="proj" basedir=".">
    <property name="abc.path" value="lib/abc-ant.jar"/>
    <taskdef resource="com/abc/antlib.xml" classpath="${abc.path}" loaderref="abc"/>
</project>
```

and the antlib.xml file in the jar looks like

```
<antlib>
    <taskdef name="abc-server" loaderref="abc" classname="com.abc.ant.Server"/>
    <taskdef name="abc-export" loaderref="abc" classname="com.abc.ant.Export"/>
    <taskdef name="abc-import" loaderref="abc" classname="com.abc.ant.Import"/>
</antlib>
```

The loaderref is important, as the *abc-export* and *abc-import* tasks call *abc-server* internally. My build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

ant.property(name: 'abc.path', value: 'lib/abc-ant.jar')

ant.taskdef(resource: "com/abc/ant/antlib.xml", classpath: ant.properties['abc.path'], loaderref: 'abc')

task server(group: "abc") {
    doLast {
        ant.abc-server(id: "id", url: 'https://www.example.com/', user: 'user@abc.com', password: 'xxx')
    }
}
```

The gradle build initializes OK, but running *server* fails with an error like:

```
> No such property: abc for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of Ant path and reference IDs, and passing the Ant project classloader as the loaderref. I also tried importing the whole Ant build, with

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'ant-' + antTargetName
}
```

But no luck. Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's this line

```
ant.abc-server(...)
```

Just like Java, Groovy method names can't contain the "-" character.

Option 1, remove the dash

```
<taskdef name="abcServer" loaderref="abc" classname="com.abc.ant.Server"/>

ant.abcServer(...)
```

Option 2, surround the method name in quotes

```
ant.'abc-server'(...)
```

Comment: thanks. I don't have control of the jar, but `ant.'abc-server'(...)` works